# Using htaccess to control session inactivity

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I have a local site running that is authenticated by an htaccess file which requires a username and password. This works great, but I want to add a feature that if the site is inactive (you walk away) for 10 minutes it will ask you for the username and password again upon refreshing/reloading a page on the site. Is there anyway to do this?

It's a Wordpress site so adding code to every single page might be a little bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP authentication hasn't any logout, nor session expiration. The credentials are sent on every request. What you want is a web-based authentication. In the case of Wordpress you may use one of the existing plugins, for example http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/basic-authentication/.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I need now is for that authentication to expire after 10 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: I don't have tried those Wordpress PLugins, but you need to set the cookie timeout to 10 minutes somehow.